# resize image to fit in div with a max width set

Tags: html, css, image, width

I have an image in my header that **I want to show as full screen with a max-width of 2000px. If the browser is wider than 2000px then the image just shows in the center of the screen.**

Also when the image stretches to fit the screen can it stay proportional with the height staying the same with the height also stretching?

Is this possible with just CSS or is JavaScript needed?

```
    <header class="front-page" role="banner">

        <div id="inner-header">
            <div id="hero-container">

                <img class="hero_img" src="http://mywebsite.com/wp-content/themes/theme_wp/images/hero_img.jpg"/>

            </div>
            <nav id="nav-sticky" role="navigation">
                <?php bones_main_nav(); ?>
            </nav>

        </div>

    </header>   

header.front-page{width:100%;height:500px;}

img.hero-img{
max-width:2000px;   
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;}
```

**#### I am not sure how to style the containing div's so they handle the image correctly.**

Comment: you are only missing: width:100%; for img.hero-img

Comment: Thanks GCyrillus that was it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use cover if you are using it as a background image.

css

`#background-div {
    background: url(../images/yourimage.jpg) no-repeat fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}`

This will automatically adjust when you resize your window.

Comment: Thanks this was actually going to be next question. You saved me another post. Since There are no other answers and this was going to be my next question I am going to mark it closed. Thanks +1

Comment: No problem man.  Enjoy.  I use that all the time.  And with all these trends of big background images, it will no doubt come in handy.